# tcl, how to grab variable value by string

Tags: variables, tcl, variable-assignment

I can do this:

```
set name john
set $name 55
puts $john

==> 55
```

I want to do the opposite, is it possible?

Something like:

```
set john 55
set name john
puts $$name

==> 55
```

Is there anything like it in tcl?

Comment: Yup.. It is pretty much the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
puts [set $name]
```